# creating a csv file from a number of different lists

Tags: python, csv

i m trying to create a CSV file from a number of different lists

the data in the lists are all either integers or floating points

i can place the field names correctly into my csv file, but when i try to add the data from my lists into new rows in the csv file, i get the TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable, error message

my code is as follows

```
    import csv
    fileName= str(input("input a file name > "))

    with open(fileName+'.csv', 'w') as csvfile:

        fieldnames = ['Generation', 'Juviniles', 'Adults', 'Seniles', 'Total']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)


        writer.writeheader()
        i=0
        for n in range (gens):
            writer.writerow({'Generation': str(i), 'Juviniles': str(juviniles[i]), 'Adults': str(adults[i]), 'Seniles': str(seniles[i]), 'Total': str(total[i]))
            i = i+1
        writer.writerow({'Generation': str(i), 'Juviniles': str(juviniles[i]), 'Adults': str(adults[i]), 'Seniles': str(seniles[i]), 'Total': str(total[i])})
```

it worked fine when i only entered the first two columns (generation and juviniles), but when i tried to extend to 5 columns, it throws me the error.

my first thought as that i had to change the data in the lists to strings (hence the str(0 functions) but no difference

any help would be greatly received.

Comment: Generally, error messages in python give a line number as well.  This could point you towards exactly _where_ you are subscripting an int

Comment: You should always post the entire traceback.  Place a ```try/except``` block around the offending lines and print the *bad* data in the ```except``` suite then re-raise the error.  It should give you an idea of what/why it is happening.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to zip together separate lists, each representing a column in the CSV file. Here is an easy way to do it:

```
import csv
from itertools import count, izip

# Some other details here
with open(fileName+'.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['Generation', 'Juviniles', 'Adults', 'Seniles', 'Total']
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(fieldnames)
    for row in izip(count(), juviniles, adults, seniles, total):
        writer.writerow(row)
```

## Discussion

- Don't need to use `DictWriter`, just use a regular `writer`: we are not dealing with dictionaries
- `count()` is a generator which generates 0, 1, 2, 3, ...
- `izip` (or `zip`) combines all of the columns to make the rows